# Search Dataframe for value in rows and return as list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies if I'm not framing the question correctly, but I have two dataframes, df1 and df2.  df1 is essentially an inventory list, and df2 is a master list.

```
df1 = [['100', '12345678'], ['100', '12345677'], ['200', '12345655'], ['300', '12345652'], ['300', '12345671'], ['100', '12345633']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['id','sku'])
```

```
data = [['100','Toy'],['200','Hammer'],['300','Guitar']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['id','name'])
```

df1 may contain multiple rows of each item, each having a different sku.

```
      id        sku
0     100       12345678
1     100       12345677
2     200       12345655
3     300       12345652
4     300       12345671
5     100       12345633
```

df2 is just a list of items

```
      id        name
0     100       Toy
1     200       Hammer
2     300       Guitar
```

I need to create a third column in df2 to reflect all associated skus from df1 based on 'id', preferably as a list of values.  Expected result would look like:

```
      id        name         skus   
0     100       Toy          ['12345678','12345677','12345633']
1     200       Hammer       ['12345655']
2     300       Guitar       ['12345652','12345671']
```

What I've tried looks like this, but I'm getting an empty list in df2['skus'] on every row.

```
gather_skus = df[df1.id.isin([df2.id])]
df2['skus'] = gather_skus.sku.tolist()
```

I've also tried a couple attempts using df.query with no luck.  Would be extremely grateful if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: You have `df1` and `data` mixed up in your first few lines of code.  Could you please fix this?

Comment: Oops - fixed.  Was summarizing as I went to keep it as short as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate your first DataFrame by `'id'` to create a list of all `'sku'`s associated with each id. Since the aggregation is guaranteed to be unique for each `'id'`, `map` those lists to the second DataFrame.

```
df2['skus'] = df2['id'].map(df1.groupby('id')['sku'].agg(list))

    id    name                            skus
0  100     Toy  [12345678, 12345677, 12345633]
1  200  Hammer                      [12345655]
2  300  Guitar            [12345652, 12345671]
```

Comment: That looks fantastic, thank you.  Running into a weird sqlalchemy error using that though, so I'm digging through that.  The original df is built using pd_read_sql_query and it's throwing a sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError that doesn't reference the original query.  Not sure what I make out of that yet.

Comment: @tnoe, hmmm I'm not sure about that, I don't have too much experience wit sqlalchemy.